# How to mirror Oracle's Solaris repo on Linux?

Tags: oracle, proxy, repository, solaris, mirror

Solaris servers in our internal network require an internal repo for updates. This repo has been configured using archives and a script from Oracle. I have an internet-facing Oracle Linux 7 server that will act as a proxy/mirror for Oracle's remote repo.

What would be the best way for me to sync Oracle's Solaris repo onto this Linux server? Or would it be easier to simply proxy our internal repo through it, when checking for updates?

I've done something similar with `yum reposync`, but this won't apply to the Solaris repositories.

Thank you!

Comment: Talk to Oracle support to find out 1) if what you propose is legitimate under the terms of your license, and 2) suggestions from them on how to do it.

Comment: Or maybe this contains the answer: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/article-howto-set-up-repos-mirror-ips.html